# How can I populate array of objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema looks like:

```
const mock =  new Schema({
   category:...,
   name:....,
   doneBy: [{
       type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'User'
   }]
})
```

Query: 'doneBy' property is an array of particular users who have done the task. When I console.log it prints only ids as "doneBy: [id1,id2,id3......]". Now I want to populate these ids to get the particular user's info. Please share the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate it in your query like so:

```
mock.find({...}).populate('doneBy')
```

If you want to populate the users but only select certain fields (for example, the username):

```
mock.find({...}).populate({ path: 'doneBy', select: { username: 1 } }) // _id will also be returned by default
```

Comment: Mr @Kowshik I queried exactly like you mentioned in first line like: mock.findOne({}).populate ('doneBy').exec((err,data)=>{console.log(data)})..........But getting error.